# Ubuntu 20.04 plays sound only through HDMI monitor

Tags: sound

My ubuntu desktop does not play any sound through speakers, connected to sound card.
It always plays through HDMI monitor, like it is the only sound playing device connected.

I have these settings, and it still plays through HDMI monitor.
[image]

When I plug my headphones - the system sees it in the 'output device', but sound still goes through HDMI.

When I remove HDMI monitor (it is my secondary monitor), then the sound works fine.

**UPD**

```
cat /proc/asound/cards

 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf220000 irq 126
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xdf080000 irq 17
```

Can you help?

Comment: please refine your question , especially hardware type and the output of `cat /proc/asound/cards` is ineresting , since it might be hardware related or auto-switched by chip

Comment: (answer updated) 
so the soundcard of your mainboard ( intel) seems to be switching , try to install `pavucontrol` , there you should be able to select the ouput port , for permanent fixing: see **card profiles** https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62818/how-can-i-switch-between-different-audio-output-hardware-using-the-shell 

OR enable both outputs https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Simultaneous_HDMI_and_analog_output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- try if `pavucontrol` lets you **select** a specific **output**
- if you don't mind having **both** **outputs** **enabled**:  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Simultaneous_HDMI_and_analog_output ( found via https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143865/how-to-enable-both-built-in-audio-output-and-hdmi-audio-output-with-pulseaudio )
- in **alsamixer** there might be a **element named** `output` or `switch output` or similar , enabling you to change output by muting/unmuting it ( also HDMI might be called something with LINE)
- if you **have more than one card** , or a card that exports multiple output ports: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62818/how-can-i-switch-between-different-audio-output-hardware-using-the-shell
- if you **have one card** providing more than one output and it might be a routing problem: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/ALSA#APlay_SPDIF.2FHDMI_output_has_incorrect_speaker_channels
- if you are **unlucky** your card might be **auto-switching** , exporting only ONE sound card to the system ( e.g. **IGP** cards on mini PC's) then it **WILL** always **cut line** for HDMI

  **Workaround:** get some audio extractor , example: https://www.reichelt.de/4khdmi-audio-extractor-n-vext3470at-p266927.html

---

Update :

i found a script in one of my projects to force asound Analog output ( run it as `root` in a `bash`-compliant shell):

```
aplay -l|grep Analog|grep -v Digital|sed 's/^card /defaults.pcm.card /g;s/:.\+device /\ndefaults.pcm.device /g'|cut -d":" -f1 > /etc/asound.conf
```

this will add a permament entry to `/etc/asound.conf`

Answer (score 1):

**found a better option**

using systemd as described below worked on startup but not when plugging devices in to an already running system.

To ignore audio when hot-plugging *and* on boot, udev rules are the better option.

Adapted from [Tell PulseAudio to ignore a USB device using udev](https://jamielinux.com/blog/tell-pulseaudio-to-ignore-a-usb-device-using-udev/):

1. use `lsusb` to identify the vendor/product id of the device you want to ignore

   ```
   $ lsusb
   Bus 006 Device 003: ID 17e9:4307 DisplayLink LAPDOCK
   # <other devices I don't care about>
   ```

   the `ID` part gives us the magic numbers
2. create a udev rules file, e.g. `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-ignore-audio-cards.rules` that sets an environment variable for pulse audio.

   For me this looked like:

   ```
   ATTRS{idVendor}=="17e9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4307", ENV{PULSE_IGNORE}="1"
   ```

   I chose the `80-` prefix for the filename arbitrarily. If you any pulseaudio related rules, make sure your new file starts with a lower number
3. reboot to ensure it takes effect

With the udev rule in place, pulseaudio ignores the device completely.

---

*previous answer:*

Ran into the same problem, and the given answers didn't work for me across restarts. I think my issue was delayed detection of cards; when pulseaudio started up it didn't see all the cards, and some combination of [`module-switch-on-connect`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-switch-on-connect) and [`module-switch-on-port-available`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-switch-on-port-available) was always resetting my choices.

I solved this by making a [systemd user unit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User) to run `pactl set_card_profile "$MY_CARD_NAME" off` when I logged in.

1. find the name of the card you don't want; hopefully the name should be enough to tell which one:

   ```
   $ pactl list cards | grep -E '(Card|Name:)'
   Card #0
       Name: alsa_card.usb-DisplayLink_LAPDOCK_U3D2338486250-02
   Card #1
       Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1
   Card #2
       Name: alsa_card.usb-Plantronics_Plantronics_Blackwire_5220_Series_2961D11C621649939CED8BF57E910BA5-00
   Card #3
       Name: alsa_card.usb-HD_Web_Camera_HD_Web_Camera_Ucamera001-02
   Card #4
       Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3
   ```

   For me, it was the "LAPDOCK" that kept stealing my audio.
2. create the systemd unit, to call `pactl` and disable the card:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p ~/.config/systemd/user
   $ nano ~/.config/systemd/user/disable-cards.service
   ```

   Add these contents, changing the `ExecStart` line to refer to the card you want to drop:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Disable card

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   Restart=on-failure
   ExecStart=pactl set-card-profile "alsa_card.usb-DisplayLink_LAPDOCK_U3D2338486250-02" off

   [Install]
   WantedBy=default.target
   ```
3. enable the service: `systemctl --user enable disable-cards`

Now when you restart systemd will keep trying to disconnect that card until it succeeds. There's probably better `systemd` config to get this running after the monitor is plugged in; each device shows up as a "unit" (e.g. in the output of `systemctl --user`) so this could be improved to work as you plug/unplug things.

The other alternative is to change your `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to use `module-switch-on-connect blacklist="REGEX_MATCHING_THE_CARD_NAME"`, but that didn't work for me; there's no way to customize `module-switch-on-port-available`, and I think that's what was selecting it for me.